Is it forbidden to interact with mlecchas?
Is there any rule especially for brahmanas to not interact with mlecchas?

Yes there are. Brihadddharma Purana compares interaction with mlecchas & speaking in mleccha language with alcohol consumption. In Brihat Tantrasara, there is a comment prohibiting the votary from speaking in mleccha language while conducting mantra-purascharana.
